Binding Adapter Not Working for Submodules in AAR (Using fat-aar Plugin)
I'm facing an issue with Data Binding Adapter when using an AAR that includes multiple submodules. I am using the fat-aar plugin to package the main module along with several submodules into a single AAR.
The problem is that while Data Binding Adapters defined in the main module are working correctly when the AAR is used in an application, the adapters defined in the submodules are not recognized. When attempting to use these submodule adapters, I get the following error:
Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView app:formatDate> that accepts parameter type 'long'
If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the Data Binding Adapters in the submodules are annotated correctly and match the expected types.
Ensured that the submodules are correctly included in the AAR using the fat-aar plugin.
Checked that there are no conflicts in dependencies or Gradle configurations.
The main module's Data Binding Adapters work without issues, but any adapters defined in the submodules do not work as expected. I suspect that something might be going wrong during the packaging process with fat-aar that prevents the submodule adapters from being included properly in the final AAR.
Environment:
Gradle version: 8.0+
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.0+
fat-aar plugin version: https://github.com/aasitnikov/fat-aar-android
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
